# Python not letting me print only once when getting the average marks

Tags: python, if-statement

hi so im new to python basically im trying to get the average of the marks but it print 3 times is there any way to print the average in function and only once

```
student = {
"name" : "Ali",
"program" :"computer programming",
"marks1":38,
"marks2":39,
"marks3": 40
}

def average():
    mark1 =student["marks1"] 
    mark2 = student["marks2"]
    mark3 = student["marks3"]
    averagemarks = mark1+mark2+mark3
    averagemarks = averagemarks/3
    print(averagemarks)
    return averagemarks



def result():
    if(average()>=90):
        print("Excellent")
    elif(50 <= average() <= 89):
        print("very good")
    elif(average()<=49):
        print("fail")

result()
```

Comment: assign `average()` to a variable and use that variable for comparison instead of calling the function 3 times

Comment: The average() function has a print statement inside it. Every time you call the function, it is printing the value of `averagemarks`. Like JacksonPro said, receive the value of average()  into a variable. Then compare that variable.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to correct.

1. You need to remove the print statement from `average()` function.
2. The function `average()` is returning a value. Try and store that into a variable. Then use that variable to check
3. The if statement to compare values can be modified a bit as I have done.

The updated code is shown below:

```
student = {
"name" : "Ali",
"program" :"computer programming",
"marks1":38,
"marks2":39,
"marks3": 40
}

def average():
    mark1 = student["marks1"] 
    mark2 = student["marks2"]
    mark3 = student["marks3"]
    return ((mark1+mark2+mark3)/3)
    
def result():
    x = average()
    
    if x >= 90:
        print("Excellent")
    elif x >= 50:
        print("very good")
    else:
        print("fail")

result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling average 3 times. So output get printed for trice.

Modify `result` function as follows.

```
def result():
    average_result = average()
    if(average_result>=90):
        print("Excellent")
    elif(50 <= average_result <= 89):
        print("very good")
    elif(average_result<=49):
        print("fail")


result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling average 3 times (if, elif, elif). So output get printed for three times.
So, you can put it in a variable so it will only execute once..

```
student = {
"name" : "Ali",
"program" :"computer programming",
"marks1":38,
"marks2":39,
"marks3": 40
}

def average():
  mark1 =student["marks1"] 
  mark2 = student["marks2"]
  mark3 = student["marks3"]
  averagemarks = mark1+mark2+mark3
  averagemarks = averagemarks/3
  print(averagemarks)
  return averagemarks



def result():
    aver = average()
    if(aver>=90):
        print("Excellent")
    elif(50 <= aver <= 89):
        print("very good")
    elif(aver<=49):
        print("fail")


result()
```

Answer (score 0):

In average function you are printing averagemarks directly. So each time you call average(). It calls function and prints averagemarks. you can try this code

```
student = {
"name" : "Ali",
"program" :"computer programming",
"marks1":38,
"marks2":39,
"marks3": 40
}

def average():
    mark1 =student["marks1"] 
    mark2 = student["marks2"]
    mark3 = student["marks3"]
    averagemarks = mark1+mark2+mark3
    averagemarks = averagemarks/3
    return averagemarks



def result():
    avg = average()
    print(avg)
    if(avg>=90):
        print("Excellent")
    elif(50 <= avg <= 89):
        print("very good")
    elif(avg<=49):
        print("fail")


result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the average() function only once.

```
student = {
"name" : "Ali",
"program" :"computer programming",
"marks1":38,
"marks2":39,
"marks3": 40}

def average():
    mark1 =student["marks1"] 
    mark2 = student["marks2"]
    mark3 = student["marks3"]
    averagemarks = mark1+mark2+mark3
    averagemarks = averagemarks/3
    print(averagemarks)
    return averagemarks


average_mark = average()

def result():
    if(average_mark >=90):
        print("Excellent")
    elif(50 <= average_mark):
        print("very good")
    else:
        print("fail")

result()
```

}

Answer (score -1):

def average remove print

```py
student = {
    "name": "Ali",
    "program": "computer programming",
    "marks1": 38,
    "marks2": 39,
    "marks3": 40
}


def average():
    mark1 = student["marks1"]
    mark2 = student["marks2"]
    mark3 = student["marks3"]
    averagemarks = mark1 + mark2 + mark3
    averagemarks = averagemarks / 3
    return averagemarks


def result():
    data = average()
    if data >= 90:
        print("Excellent")
    elif 50 <= data <= 89:
        print("very good")
    elif data <= 49:
        print("fail")


result()
```

Comment: you are calling the function 3 times. you should instead receive the value into a variable and compare that (inside the result() function)

Comment: OK, it's my fault.